# NPM: Depending on a local ES6 module (without transpiling)

Tags: javascript, npm, ecmascript-6

I'm developing two npm modules locally, A and B, and A has B as its dependency.

To facilite development I'm using `npm link` to symlink package folders; so inside A's node_modules there is a symlink to B's project folder.

When starting up A by running `node --harmony` the runtime complains about B using ES6 language features. However, A's own usage of ES6 language features is fine.

**How can I use a non-transpiled ES6 module as a dependency?**

Comment: For now I'm using babel to transpile, but would be interesting to know the answer to this question regardless :)

Comment: Is there any update on this? I'm running into the same issue with a front end project I'm working on and this issue comes up when I'm trying to test using `jest`. Module B is the only node_module in A that is NOT transpiled to ES5, and for whatever reason, I cannot get Jest to transpile B into ES5 syntax from within A despite `babel-jest` being bundled with it. So is what I'm reading correct in that I have to transpile B locally within itself and then export the transpiled B for A to use?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your eventual goal, but when I develop a module I need (or other people need) to depend on, I place an es5 file in the dist folder, and depend on that. This way the es6 file stays for developing purposes and the es5 file is generated dynamically by babel for consumption.

So just like you're using babel to transpile your `A` module, I'd do the same for the `B` module and depend on that.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing currently. My goal is just to have a very minimal setup, so I wanted to use ES6 without any transpiling (all my stuff is running on Node and not in the browser.).

Comment: Can you post an example of what this looks like? It would be very helpful since I'm encountering the same problem and not well versed in the arts of transpiling and exporting transpiled dependencies.